# M2 module structure api directory

Tags: magento2, interface

I am developing a m2 module.

Should i put all of my interfaces in an api directory?

Core magento sees to do this but im not sure if this is official guidelines or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is just convention, you could use a different location, but you should not.

Here is little explanation for interface:-
The repository interface goes into the Api/ folder. In Api/, create a PHP interface with the methods you want to expose. According to Magento 2 conventions all interface names end in the suffix Interface. Magento 2 repositories are part of the domain logic of a module. That means, there is no fixed set of methods a repository has to implement.
It depends entirely on the purpose of the module.
Data model interface are kept under Api/Data folder, which mainly have getter and setter functions.
Another one that we have is ExtensibleDataInterface. This interface is only required if you want other modules to be able to add attributes to your entity. These are also placed under Api/data.

You can refer this [link](http://vinaikopp.com/2017/02/18/magento2_repositories_interfaces_and_webapi/), it explains them well.